# Deploying a node js backend to a shared hosting

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, hosting, cpanel

I am trying to deploy an app on my shared hosting service using cPanel.

My provider has the classic 'setup node js app' in the panel, i used it to activate my app under the route mywebsite.com/api.

[image]

i also  hosted my Angular frontend under public_html with the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  DirectoryIndex disabled  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

my Front end app works but when i try to send a POST request to my backend .i.e (mywebsite/api/login) it returns the html frontend as a response.

**here is what it returns :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my frontend app</title>
    <base href="./">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**is there something i missed ?**

BTW :

- my frontend is hosted under mywebsite.com
- my backend is hosted under mywebsite.com/api
- all my angular services are pointing towards /api/*

when i access my backend from mywebsite.com/api i get this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to host the node js app on port 50000, this way i could contact it easily from the frontend. instead of using the classical setup node js app in cpanel.